# Web app in standalone, camera is black when app is coming back from background?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Im using the camera to take a picture in my web app and it works fine when I start the app the first time, but if I close the app and then return from being in the background then the camera screen is black and I can´t take a picture!?

Im using this to open the camera.

```
<input type="file" id="files2" name="files[]" multiple accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

This is working all the time if I open the app in Safari, but not when it is coming back from the background in standalone mode.

I have tried to reload the page when I come back from the background, but no luck.

I think this was working in the earlier iOS.
Any input really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug in iOS https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206219. Hopefully, Apple WebKit Team will fix it soon!

Comment: Thanks, Dmytro. I guess I just have to wait for the next iOS and hope for the best!